# Adding to a list in flutter updates all the items in the list

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a list of lists and every time I add to it it goes to the first list and updates it with new values. Any way to get it to not update the values in the first set?

`List<bool> routineSelectedDays = [false, true, true, true, true, true, false];`

`List listOfSelectedDays = [];`

```
   ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: (){
      listOfSelectedDays.add(routineSelectedDays);
     },  
     child: Text('Add Step')
   ),
```

Complete code:

```
class CustomRoutine2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomRoutine2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomRoutine2> createState() => _CustomRoutine2State();
}

class _CustomRoutine2State extends State<CustomRoutine2> {
  List<String> day = ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'];
  List<bool> routineSelectedDays = [false, true, true, true, true, true, false];
  List listOfSelectedDays = [];

  List newList = [];

  int selectedIndex = 0;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
        child: SizedBox(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 90,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: day.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: DaySelectorButton(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          routineSelectedDays[index] =
                          !routineSelectedDays[index];
                         });
                      },
                      day: day[index],
                      toggle: routineSelectedDays[index],
                    ),
                  );
                }),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
                listOfSelectedDays.add(routineSelectedDays);
                print(listOfSelectedDays);
              }, child: Text('Add Step')),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
              }, child: Text('DEV'))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class DaySelectorButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const DaySelectorButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.toggle,
    required this.onTap,
    required this.day
  }) : super(key: key);

  final bool toggle;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final String day;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      customBorder: const CircleBorder(),
      child: Ink(
        height: 40,
        width: 40,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: toggle ? kToggleEnabled : kToggleDisabled,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            day,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: toggle ? Colors.black : Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
flutter: [true, true, true, true, true, true, true]
flutter: [[true, true, true, true, true, true, true]]
flutter: [false, false, true, true, true, true, true]
flutter: [[false, false, true, true, true, true, true], [false, false, true, true, true, true, true]]
```

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve

Comment: add a unique list to a list without the first list getting updated with new values

Comment: Everything is working as expected. From where is this output comming ? can you produce the print(...) code, because the above produced code should output correct values

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.. I updated with the complete code. I think my issue may be coming from the listview.builder but not sure why.

Comment: Please add the `DaySelectorButton` method in the code, Because without that the code is working just fine , There is problem in `DaySelectorButton`

Comment: Actually it is working just fine !!, Can you restart your emulator and try again

Comment: Try changing the values of the buttons, then press the 'add step' button and look at the list. You will see that the values of the first list have changed.

Comment: I see this. Give me sometime. I'll get back to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the reason for the above behavior after some research,

It's because,

- same instance of `routineSelectedDays` is referred everytime `listOfSelectedDays.add(routineSelectedDays)` is called.
- So changing `routineSelectedDays` will change all instances of `routineSelectedDays` in `listOfSelectedDays`.

To overcome this problem, ***we need to add copies instead of adding the actual object***. i.e

Change

```
listOfSelectedDays.add(routineSelectedDays);
```

to

```
listOfSelectedDays.add([...routineSelectedDays]);
```

This will send the copy of the object instead of the actual object itself.

Output Now:

```
I/flutter ( 5565): [[false, false, true, true, true, true, false]]
I/flutter ( 5565): [[false, false, true, true, true, true, false], [false, false, false, true, true, true, false]]
```

Comment: Oh man thank you so much. This bug pretty much ruined my Christmas lol!

Comment: Happy to hear , You got through ! Have a beautiful Christmas Eve 

Answer (score 0):

declare routine Selected Days and list Of Selected Days before the build method

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).